# Laravel HasMany RealtionShip Doesnot Work

Tags: laravel

User Model

```
 public function teachers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Teacher::class);
    }
```

Teacher Model

```
 public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

TeacherController

```
 public function index()
    {
        $role_user = DB::table('roles')->where('role', 'teacher')->first();
        $role_id = $role_user->id;
        $users = User::all()->where('role_id',$role_id);


        return view('admin.teacher.index')
            ->with('users',$users);
    }
```

In View

```
 <td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">{{dd( $teacher->teachers->designation)}}</td>
```

It Gives An Error like this
 Property [designation] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: I don't see where you declare ` $teacher`

Comment: you should call your relationship on in this line: 
$users = User::with('teachers')->where('role_id',$role_id)->get();